# Controlling Flash Player

Tags: .net, flash

I am looking for a way to press buttons or just control an online flash player 'game' but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Until now I've been using `WebBrowser` and `WebRequest` for normal navigating on websites though this is definitely different. Any links that may be helpful?

Comment: Are you able to actually display the Flash content? If yes, are you saying the issue is now it doesn't respond to clicks (appears frozen)? Take this [**example link**](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3keyboard/index.php) if you open in usual browser (Firefox etc) you click the Flash app to get focus and ten can control by keyboard. What happens if you load same link in your `.net` project and click it for focus? Does it now respond to keyboard buttons?

Comment: PS: last resort try : loading [**SWF**](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3keyboard/tutorial-demo.swf) file (Flash app) directly into your `.net` project. If not responding to mouse or keyboard then forget it as not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Flash object is downloaded to the client and run separately from the browser (its an `<embed>`ed object) - thus is cannot be controlled, unless the Flash program itself is built in a way it can receive external commands from the web page it's embedded in (like javascript commands).

Comment: Ah okay, then I guess I can create a macro for it only, thanks!